# How can Pichay be president of the Philippine chess federation and sentenced to imprisonment re conviction of graft?

Tags: corruption, philippines, sports

**Edit**: Quick clarification. I notice when people talk about why Wesley So left the Philippines to play for the US, people say it's about corruption in the Philippine government. Apparently maybe it's just corruption in the Philippine chess federation, an NGO, rather than corruption in the government. Either this question should be re-opened or I made an understandable honest mistake based on the mistakes of others.

---

In the Philippines, there's this corrupt politician [Prospero 'Butch' Pichay Jr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prospero_Pichay_Jr.#Controversies) who is the recently [re-elected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prospero_Pichay_Jr.#Personal_life) NCFP (national chess federation of the Philippines) president. (Kinda like [Arkady Dvorkovich](https://twitter.com/FIDE_chess/status/1556191591773380608) in international chess except without the [corruption...maybe](https://twitter.com/FightForChess/status/1556215381408325632).)

**June 2022** - [Pichay guilty of graft over P780 million LWUA funds misuse](https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/1608862/pichay-guilty-of-graft-over-p780-million-lwua-funds-misuse) and [Ex-LWUA Administrator Pichay convicted in 2009 purchase of Express Savings Bank](https://mb.com.ph/2022/06/09/ex-lwua-administrator-pichay-convicted-in-2009-purchase-of-express-savings-bank/)

> The anti-graft court’s Fourth Division has sentenced Pichay and former LWUA financial service head Wilfredo Feleo Jr. to serve six to 10 years of imprisonment for each count of graft conviction.  The two are also perpetually disqualified from holding public office.

**July 2022** - Re-elected as NCFP president - see [Link 1](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=pfbid0E76dDNo5LwGnGqtP6FR1W97kfpPXrhVK7YU7BDzu3hvnmaJAiZPm1jGW9AZxtWpwl&id=107037408127720), [Link 2](https://journalnews.com.ph/pichay-reelected-ncfp-president/), [Link 3](https://manilastandard.net/sports/314246097/new-ncfp-officers-inducted.html)

**August 2022** - [Court affirms Pichay conviction](https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/1645895/court-affirms-pichay-conviction)

**September 2022** - still the president.

[National Youth and Schools Chess unfolds in Dapitan](https://mb.com.ph/2022/09/16/national-youth-and-schools-chess-unfolds-in-dapitan/)

> Apart from Jalosjos, expected to grace the opener are Grandmaster Eugene Torre, National Chess Federation of the Philippines president/chair Butch Pichay and chief executive officer GM Jayson Gonzales and host city tourism chief Apple Marie Agolong.

**October 2022** - Just 7 hours ago there was this article released that says...still the president.

[PH chessers leave for World Juniors Under-20 chess championships](http://philboxing.com/news/story-164059.html)

> "We expect these young and talented players to perform well as usual and bring honor to the country," said coach Neri. "Go Philippines. Laban Pinas. Laban para sa bayan." said chief executive officer Grandmaster Jayson Gonzales of the National Chess Federation under the leadership of it's chairman/president Rep. Prospero "Butch" Arreza Pichay Jr.

Question: **Is Pichay president while in prison?**

Note: [Pichay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCU5LwCCvOg) screwed over [Filipino](https://www.chess.com/article/view/wesley-so-interview-chess-was-a-way-out)-born [American](https://youtube.com/watch?v=GsikAfMrNQA) chess grandmaster [Wesley So](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/324239/african-american-or-filipino-american-how-do-you-distinguish-americans-of-a) (defending [US chess](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ipCqNeGb2M) champion and defending and inaugural world [Fischer random](https://www.fide.com/news/2024) chess champion) and then [lied about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0J3K-3_xCzY).

Comment: VTC not about governments, etc. It appears the answer would be in the rules of the NCFP or FIDE, thus a *toned-downed* question about the rules for presidency may be on-topic at [Chess SE](https://chess.stackexchange.com/) (check the help center); but both NCFP and FIDE are non-governmental organizations (NGOs) and the question does not appear to be about the government of the Philippines.

Comment: @RickSmith Oh thanks for the info. So you'll be president while in prison basically? You can be convicted and have to pay money and still be president but what if you're in prison?

Comment: I think this is on topic, as it concerns a political figure. But I'm not clear why the OP finds this hard to understand.  NCFP can have a prisioner as their President, if they want. It's a private organisation. They can have a jellyfish if they want, or seven presidents, one for each day of the week.

Comment: @JamesK 1 - lol thanks well i wanna know why it's not, say, looking bad or something for the NCFP? I imagine people may ask 'Why are you (RE-)electing a convict?' - That's totally off-topic I bet right? 2 - Do you disagree with Rick Smith that it's off-topic just because it's about a non-political organisation (is non-political different from non-governmental?) even if it's about a politician?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chess Federation is an NGO; it's a private club not an branch of the government. There's no law that says convicted criminals can't be presidents of private clubs.

Of course if the club president is in prison, he may not be able to do many of the things you'd expect the president to do. He won't be able to attend meetings, give speeches about chess, visit school chess clubs. The club may be embarrassed by having a criminal as their president, but there is no law against it.

Comment: Oh thanks for the info. So you'll be president while in prison basically? You can be convicted and have to pay money and still be president but what if you're in prison?

Comment: It is entirely a matter for the chess club of the Phillipines.  This is a private matter, not a public one.

Comment: Ah I see I see lol. k thanks. p.s. nice edit 4 hours later. LOL.

Comment: James K, I notice when people talk about why Wesley So left the Philippines to play for the US, people say it's about corruption in the Philippine government. Apparently maybe it's just corruption in the Philippine chess federation, an NGO, rather than corruption in the government. (Have you any idea?) But if it's to do with corruption in the philippine government, then this could possibly be on-topic?